# Can Dolphin file-manager administer the desktop outside Plasma/KDE?

Tags: linux, file-manager, dolphin

I am trying to [set Dolphin to manage the desktop in LXQt installed on top of Kubuntu 18, instead of PCManFM-Qt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/467874/set-dolphin-to-manage-the-desktop-in-lxqt), but [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/231942/47206) says that Dolphin cannot do that, (also [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/291102/47206)) not  even on Plasma KDE, but that Kwin does it.

I don't understand exactly if that's correct and what could that mean. As LXQt desktop is installed in Kubuntu, Kwin is installed on my system - and I have set it also the default window manager in the LXQt desktop environment.

What I expect is a folder clicked on the desktop to be opened in Dolphin, and the right-click context menu of a selected file/folder to be the one set for Dolphin - instead of PCManFM-Qt.

I am posting this in order to get a more clear answer.